# Rendering nested arrays of objects using handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I am having trouble rendering nested arrays of objects within hbs.

I need to display every images and their corresponding links together on a webpage (example: Image "1" have a link of "a").

Below code does not work, is there any other solution for that?

Server.js:

```
res.render('index.hbs', {

    images: [ 1, 2, 3],

    links: [a, b, c] 

   }

);
```

index.hbs:

```
{{#each images}}

     {{#each links}}

          <img> {{this}} </img> // should display all images

          <a> {{this}} </a> // should display all links

     {{/each}}           

{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rearrange your input to work with only one array:

```
var images = [1, 2, 3];
var links = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var objects = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i ++) { 
    objects[i] = { image: images[i], link: links[i] }; 
}

var data = { objects: objects };

res.render('index.hbs', data);
```

Then you can iterate over it easily:

```
{{#each objects}}
    <img> {{image}} </img> // should display all images
    <a> {{link}} </a> // should display all links
{{/each}}
```

You can see this chunk of code working [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KQLqRr?editors=1010).

Comment: AWESOME!! working perfectly!,

But can please explain:

var objects = images.reduce((acc, ele, idx) => acc.concat({ 
    image: ele,
    link: links[idx]
}), []);
var data = { objects: objects };

got confused. thanks

Comment: oh, i'm just creating an array of object which consists `{ image: images[idx], link: links[idx] }`. you could either use a for which is simpler: `var objects = []; for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i ++) { objects[i] = { image: images[i], link: links[i] } }`. you can thumb up a response if you found it useful. I've just edited using a for clause